# Barplot with a distinguish color for significant positive and negative p value

Tags: r, bar-chart, analysis, p-value, pearson-correlation

my data set contains 12 months and 4 seasons (pre-monsoon, monsoon, postmonsoon,dry-season) and their r and p-value in relation to ring width index

here is the code I used,

```
k <- read.csv("macro_r_p.csv",TRUE,",")

k
cols <- c("azure3", "red") [(k$p < 0.05)+1] 
barplot(k$r,names.arg=k$parameter,ylab="Correlation coefficient",col=cols,
        main = expression("T"[max]), las=2)
```

but, I could only manage a color for both positive and negative significant p value (p < 0.05). I want one different color for positive significant relation and another different color for negative significant relation.  It would be helpful to give me the code to get a sophisticated text font (a bit larger). Also, my graph height was not adjusted properly.

Comment: There is no such thing as a negative p-value. P-values are probabilities that range from 0 to 1. You must be referring to a test statistic?

Comment: right, negative correlation between Ring Width Index and climate variable

Comment: `sig <- ifelse(k$p > .05, 1, ifelse(k$r > 0, 2, 3)` will let you define 3 colors.